# Apache2 using up all my memory and stalling my wordpress instance (mysql)

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, memory, wordpress, memory-usage

### Environment

- Ubuntu 12.04 / 1GB RAM / 40GB DISK / 1 CPU (RACKSPACE)
- Wordpress 3.9
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
- Apache2
- mod_php5
- mod_rewrite

When a fresh restart of `apache2` and `mysql` accessing my website a couple of time is enough to use up all the 1GB memory, which stalls `mysql` hence my wordpress website.

### After a restart of services

```
$ service apache2 restart
$ service mysql restart
$ atop

ATOP - staging-www                                               2014/07/30  23:52:11                                               ------                                                10s elapsed
PRC | sys    0.02s  | user   0.00s  |               | #proc     83  | #trun      1  | #tslpi    90  |               | #tslpu     0  | #zombie    0  | clones    59  |               | #exit     59  |
CPU | sys       1%  | user      0%  | irq       0%  |               | idle     99%  | wait      0%  |               |               | steal     0%  | guest     0%  | curf 2.59GHz  | curscal   ?%  |
CPL | avg1    0.00  |               | avg5    0.06  | avg15   0.21  |               |               | csw      786  |               | intr     252  |               |               | numcpu     1  |
MEM | tot   991.5M  | free  850.3M  | cache  51.5M  |               | dirty   0.1M  | buff    2.9M  | slab   15.2M  |               |               |               |               |               |
SWP | tot     0.0M  | free    0.0M  |               |               |               |               |               |               |               |               | vmcom 387.9M  | vmlim 495.8M  |
NET | transport     | tcpi       2  | tcpo       3  | udpi       0  | udpo       0  | tcpao      0  | tcppo      0  | tcprs      0  | tcpie      0  | tcpor      0  | udpnp      0  | udpip      0  |
NET | network       | ipi        2  | ipo        3  |               | ipfrw      0  | deliv      2  |               |               |               |               | icmpi      0  | icmpo      0  |
NET | eth0    ----  | pcki       2  | pcko       3  | si    0 Kbps  | so    0 Kbps  | coll       0  |               | mlti       0  | erri       0  | erro       0  | drpi       0  | drpo       0  |

  PID       RUID           EUID            THR        SYSCPU        USRCPU        VGROW        RGROW        RDDSK        WRDSK       ST       EXC       S       CPUNR        CPU       CMD        1/2
30194       root           root              1         0.01s         0.00s           0K           0K           0K           0K       --         -       R           0         0%       atop
30409       root           -
```

Note the `free  850.3M`

### I access my wordpress website once

```
ATOP - staging-www                                               2014/07/30  23:54:11                                               ------                                                10s elapsed
PRC | sys    0.09s  | user   0.19s  |               | #proc     90  | #trun      1  | #tslpi   112  |               | #tslpu     0  | #zombie    0  | clones    60  |               | #exit     59  |
CPU | sys       2%  | user      2%  | irq       0%  |               | idle     96%  | wait      0%  |               |               | steal     0%  | guest     0%  | curf 2.59GHz  | curscal   ?%  |
CPL | avg1    0.00  |               | avg5    0.04  | avg15   0.19  |               |               | csw     1503  |               | intr     406  |               |               | numcpu     1  |
MEM | tot   991.5M  | free  388.3M  | cache 125.8M  |               | dirty   0.2M  | buff    4.4M  | slab   17.0M  |               |               |               |               |               |
SWP | tot     0.0M  | free    0.0M  |               |               |               |               |               |               |               |               | vmcom   1.0G  | vmlim 495.8M  |
DSK |         xvda  | busy      0%  | read       0  |               | write     19  | KiB/r      0  | KiB/w     16  | MBr/s   0.00  |               | MBw/s   0.03  | avq     3.00  | avio 0.21 ms  |
NET | transport     | tcpi      19  | tcpo      22  | udpi       0  | udpo       0  | tcpao      0  | tcppo      0  | tcprs      0  | tcpie      0  | tcpor      1  | udpnp      0  | udpip      0  |
NET | network       | ipi       19  | ipo       22  |               | ipfrw      0  | deliv     19  |               |               |               |               | icmpi      0  | icmpo      0  |
NET | eth0    ----  | pcki      17  | pcko      20  | si    0 Kbps  | so    5 Kbps  | coll       0  |               | mlti       0  | erri       0  | erro       0  | drpi       0  | drpo       0  |
NET | lo      ----  | pcki       2  | pcko       2  | si    0 Kbps  | so    0 Kbps  | coll       0  |               | mlti       0  | erri       0  | erro       0  | drpi       0  | drpo       0  |

  PID       RUID           EUID            THR        SYSCPU        USRCPU        VGROW        RGROW        RDDSK        WRDSK       ST       EXC       S       CPUNR        CPU       CMD        1/2
30587       www-data       www-data          1         0.05s         0.17s        4572K        5796K           0K           0K       --         -       S           0         2%       apache2
30599       mysql          mysql            16         0.02s         0.01s           0K         -84K           0K         288K       --         -       S           0         0%       mysqld
30194       root           root              1         0.02s         0.01s           0K           0K           0K           0K       --         -       R           0         0%       atop
30577       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.00s       -9480K       -8960K           0K           0K       --         -       S           0         0%       apache2
30559       root           root              1         0.00s         0.00s           0K          20K           0K           0K       --         -       S           0         0%       apache2
30877       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.00s       218.6M        5364K           0K           0K       N-         -       S           0         0%       apache2
  457       root           root              1         0.00s         0.00s           0K           0K           0K          36K       --         -       S           0         0%       xe-daemon
30936       root           root              1         0.00s         0.00s        4312K         348K           0K           0K       N-         -       S           0         0%       sleep
30513       root           -                 0         0.00s         0.00s           0K           0K            -            -       -E         0       E           -         0%       <sleep>
```

note the `free  388.3M`

### Access a second time the same URL (home page)

```
ATOP - staging-www                                               2014/07/30  23:55:51                                               ------                                                10s elapsed
PRC | sys    0.60s  | user   2.77s  |               | #proc     90  | #trun      1  | #tslpi   112  |               | #tslpu     0  | #zombie    0  | clones     4  |               | #exit      0  |
CPU | sys       6%  | user     28%  | irq       0%  |               | idle     65%  | wait      0%  |               |               | steal     0%  | guest     0%  | curf 2.59GHz  | curscal   ?%  |
CPL | avg1    0.00  |               | avg5    0.03  | avg15   0.17  |               |               | csw     4154  |               | intr    1488  |               |               | numcpu     1  |
MEM | tot   991.5M  | free   81.4M  | cache 125.8M  |               | dirty   0.0M  | buff    4.5M  | slab   17.1M  |               |               |               |               |               |
SWP | tot     0.0M  | free    0.0M  |               |               |               |               |               |               |               |               | vmcom   1.3G  | vmlim 495.8M  |
DSK |         xvda  | busy      0%  | read       0  |               | write     31  | KiB/r      0  | KiB/w      9  | MBr/s   0.00  |               | MBw/s   0.03  | avq     0.00  | avio 0.00 ms  |
NET | transport     | tcpi     212  | tcpo     140  | udpi       2  | udpo       2  | tcpao      2  | tcppo      8  | tcprs      5  | tcpie      0  | tcpor      2  | udpnp      0  | udpip      0  |
NET | network       | ipi      214  | ipo      135  |               | ipfrw      0  | deliv    214  |               |               |               |               | icmpi      0  | icmpo      0  |
NET | eth0    ----  | pcki     196  | pcko     117  | si   93 Kbps  | so   27 Kbps  | coll       0  |               | mlti       0  | erri       0  | erro       0  | drpi       0  | drpo       0  |
NET | lo      ----  | pcki      18  | pcko      18  | si    2 Kbps  | so    2 Kbps  | coll       0  |               | mlti       0  | erri       0  | erro       0  | drpi       0  | drpo       0  |

  PID       RUID           EUID            THR        SYSCPU        USRCPU        VGROW        RGROW        RDDSK        WRDSK       ST       EXC       S       CPUNR        CPU       CMD        1/1
30592       www-data       www-data          1         0.17s         0.74s       96188K       98620K           0K           4K       --         -       S           0         9%       apache2
30588       www-data       www-data          1         0.14s         0.77s       73932K       76228K           0K           4K       --         -       S           0         9%       apache2
30589       www-data       www-data          1         0.12s         0.51s       68408K       72084K           0K           4K       --         -       S           0         6%       apache2
30604       www-data       www-data          1         0.10s         0.49s       68408K       72084K           0K           0K       --         -       S           0         6%       apache2
30599       mysql          mysql            16         0.06s         0.24s           0K          12K           0K         256K       --         -       S           0         3%       mysqld
30194       root           root              1         0.01s         0.01s           0K           0K           0K           0K       --         -       R           0         0%       atop
30597       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.01s         676K        3208K           0K           4K       --         -       S           0         0%       apache2
30590       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.00s         676K        3212K           0K           0K       --         -       S           0         0%       apache2
30598       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.00s         156K        1000K           0K           4K       --         -       S           0         0%       apache2
30605       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.00s         156K        1000K           0K           8K       --         -       S           0         0%       apache2
  150       root           root              1         0.00s         0.00s           0K           0K           0K          52K       --         -       S           0         0%       kjournald
```

Note `free   81.4M`

### After reloading the same page 4/5 times

I am getting `Error establishing a database connection` instead of my home page

```
ATOP - staging-www                                               2014/07/30  23:57:31                                               ------                                                10s elapsed
PRC | sys    0.52s  | user   0.19s  |               | #proc     89  | #trun      1  | #tslpi    96  |               | #tslpu     0  | #zombie    0  | clones    71  |               | #exit     63  |
CPU | sys       6%  | user      3%  | irq       0%  |               | idle     80%  | wait     11%  |               |               | steal     0%  | guest     0%  | curf 2.59GHz  | curscal   ?%  |
CPL | avg1    0.68  |               | avg5    0.19  | avg15   0.21  |               |               | csw    11267  |               | intr    8436  |               |               | numcpu     1  |
MEM | tot   991.5M  | free   61.9M  | cache  34.6M  |               | dirty   0.2M  | buff    1.0M  | slab   15.2M  |               |               |               |               |               |
SWP | tot     0.0M  | free    0.0M  |               |               |               |               |               |               |               |               | vmcom   1.2G  | vmlim 495.8M  |
PAG | scan   64113  |               |               | stall      0  |               |               |               |               | swin       0  |               |               | swout      0  |
DSK |         xvda  | busy     14%  | read    7704  |               | write     18  | KiB/r     26  | KiB/w     16  | MBr/s  19.79  |               | MBw/s   0.03  | avq     3.53  | avio 0.18 ms  |
NET | transport     | tcpi     110  | tcpo      69  | udpi       2  | udpo       2  | tcpao      0  | tcppo      6  | tcprs      8  | tcpie      0  | tcpor      0  | udpnp      0  | udpip      0  |
NET | network       | ipi      112  | ipo       74  |               | ipfrw      0  | deliv    112  |               |               |               |               | icmpi      0  | icmpo      0  |
NET | eth0    ----  | pcki     112  | pcko      74  | si   38 Kbps  | so   11 Kbps  | coll       0  |               | mlti       0  | erri       0  | erro       0  | drpi       0  | drpo       0  |

  PID       RUID           EUID            THR        SYSCPU        USRCPU        VGROW        RGROW        RDDSK        WRDSK       ST       EXC       S       CPUNR        CPU       CMD        1/3
30574       www-data       www-data          1         0.32s         0.11s       29956K       29096K       148.1M           0K       --         -       S           0         4%       apache2
30589       www-data       www-data          1         0.02s         0.02s        2104K        2648K        6308K           4K       --         -       S           0         0%       apache2
31118       mysql          -                 0         0.02s         0.01s           0K           0K            -            -       NE         1       E           -         0%       <mysqld>
31154       mysql          -                 0         0.02s         0.01s           0K           0K            -            -       NE         1       E           -         0%       <mysqld>
  814       root           root              2         0.02s         0.00s           0K         164K       17032K           0K       --         -       S           0         0%       nova-agent
30586       www-data       www-data          1         0.01s         0.01s         520K         172K          80K           0K       --         -       S           0         0%       apache2
    1       root           root              1         0.02s         0.00s           0K         352K       409.3M        9480K       --         -       S           0         0%       init
   21       root           root              1         0.02s         0.00s           0K           0K           0K           0K       --         -       S           0         0%       kworker/0:1
30870       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.01s           0K       -2608K         432K           0K       --         -       S           0         0%       apache2
30568       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.01s           0K        -548K          16K           4K       --         -       S           0         0%       apache2
30585       www-data       www-data          1         0.01s         0.00s           0K        -672K          44K           0K       --         -       S           0         0%       apache2
30194       root           root              1         0.01s         0.00s           0K           0K           8K           0K       --         -       R           0         0%       atop
```

### Trying to restart mysql

```
root@staging-www:~# service mysql restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
start: Job failed to start
root@staging-www:~#
```

### It gets back on his feet after:

```
root@staging-www:~# service apache2 restart && service mysql restart
```

---

This obviously not due to a traffic, one single request already uses the memory to a third (?) and the subsequent requests just use up everything and stalls my machine and the memory never gets recovered (??)

On production I have upgraded to 2 GB, but I have the feelings that something is wrong with my setup, and I wonder if that could be something with my wordpress code. But I don't know where to start really.

The apache2 log `/var/log/apache2/error.log` show no errors.

Any other logs I should look at?

Does apache2 actually need 2 GB to be able to run? (that's seems unlikely right?)

### UPDATE - My current `apache2.conf`

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          16
    MinSpareServers       16
    MaxSpareServers       32
    ServerLimit           400
    MaxClients            400
    MaxRequestsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>


<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          4
    ServerLimit           16
    MaxClients            1024
    MinSpareThreads       64
    MaxSpareThreads       192
    ThreadsPerChild       64
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

### UPDATE - New tuning (still having memory issue)

```
# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers       10
    ServerLimit           400
    MaxClients            150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    ServerLimit           16
    MaxClients            150
    MinSpareThreads       25
    MaxSpareThreads       75
    ThreadsPerChild       64
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

I have tuned down my MPM but I am still out of memory

```
ATOP - staging-www                                               2014/07/31  00:57:11                                               ------                                                10s elapsed
PRC | sys    0.89s  | user   2.90s  |               | #proc     79  | #trun      1  | #tslpi   101  |               | #tslpu     0  | #zombie    0  | clones    11  |               | #exit      0  |
CPU | sys       9%  | user     30%  | irq       0%  |               | idle     61%  | wait      1%  |               |               | steal     0%  | guest     0%  | curf 2.59GHz  | curscal   ?%  |
CPL | avg1    0.05  |               | avg5    0.39  | avg15   0.30  |               |               | csw     5914  |               | intr    2938  |               |               | numcpu     1  |
MEM | tot   991.5M  | free  410.6M  | cache 122.2M  |               | dirty   0.2M  | buff    3.7M  | slab   16.1M  |               |               |               |               |               |
SWP | tot     0.0M  | free    0.0M  |               |               |               |               |               |               |               |               | vmcom 877.0M  | vmlim 495.8M  |
DSK |         xvda  | busy      2%  | read    1425  |               | write     16  | KiB/r     34  | KiB/w     17  | MBr/s   4.82  |               | MBw/s   0.03  | avq     3.26  | avio 0.17 ms  |
NET | transport     | tcpi     179  | tcpo     116  | udpi       2  | udpo       2  | tcpao      2  | tcppo      8  | tcprs      1  | tcpie      0  | tcpor      2  | udpnp      0  | udpip      0  |
NET | network       | ipi      181  | ipo      111  |               | ipfrw      0  | deliv    181  |               |               |               |               | icmpi      0  | icmpo      0  |
NET | eth0    ----  | pcki     163  | pcko      93  | si   80 Kbps  | so   28 Kbps  | coll       0  |               | mlti       0  | erri       0  | erro       0  | drpi       0  | drpo       0  |
NET | lo      ----  | pcki      18  | pcko      18  | si    2 Kbps  | so    2 Kbps  | coll       0  |               | mlti       0  | erri       0  | erro       0  | drpi       0  | drpo       0  |

  PID       RUID           EUID            THR        SYSCPU        USRCPU        VGROW        RGROW        RDDSK        WRDSK       ST       EXC       S       CPUNR        CPU       CMD        1/1
 6154       www-data       www-data          1         0.19s         0.77s       83896K       86248K          40K           0K       --         -       S           0        10%       apache2
 6152       www-data       www-data          1         0.18s         0.78s       73932K       76228K         660K           0K       --         -       S           0        10%       apache2
 6153       www-data       www-data          1         0.11s         0.53s       68408K       72084K           0K           4K       --         -       S           0         6%       apache2
 6449       www-data       www-data          1         0.16s         0.47s       285.4M       77444K           0K           0K       N-         -       S           0         6%       apache2
 6179       mysql          mysql            16         0.20s         0.35s       320.0M       49216K       48508K         256K       --         -       S           0         6%       mysqld
 6147       root           root              1         0.02s         0.00s           0K           0K           0K           0K       --         -       S           0         0%       apache2
30194       root           root              1         0.02s         0.00s           0K           0K           0K           0K       --         -       R           0         0%       atop
    4       root           root              1         0.01s         0.00s           0K           0K           0K           0K       --         -       S           0         0%       kworker/0:0
 6155       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.00s         148K        1000K          36K           4K       --         -       S           0         0%       apache2
 6156       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.00s         148K        1000K          36K           4K       --         -       S           0         0%       apache2
 6445       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.00s       218.8M        6360K          36K           4K       N-         -       S           0         0%       apache2
 6448       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.00s       218.7M        6360K          56K           8K       N-         -       S           0         0%       apache2
 6450       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.00s       218.6M        5360K           0K           0K       N-         -       S           0         0%       apache2
 6451       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.00s       218.6M        5360K           0K           0K       N-         -       S           0         0%       apache2
 6452       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.00s       218.6M        5360K           0K           0K       N-         -       S           0         0%       apache2
 6455       www-data       www-data          1         0.00s         0.00s       218.6M        5360K           0K           0K       N-         -       S           0         0%       apache2
  962       ntp            ntp               1         0.00s         0.00s           0K         100K           0K           0K       --         -       S           0         0%       ntpd
  150       root           root              1         0.00s         0.00s           0K           0K           0K          48K       --         -       S           0         0%       kjournald
```

I have restarted `apache2` to take in account the new config. but that doesn't seem enough.

Looks like it didn't take in account my settings, I have more that 5 `apache2` services started.

When accessing my website through 5/6 url in different tabs of my browser I run into the same out of memory issue.

```
PRC | sys    0.60s  | user   3.05s  |               | #proc     80  | #trun      4  | #tslpi   105  |               | #tslpu     0  | #zombie    0  | clones     7  |               | #exit      0  |
CPU | sys       6%  | user     31%  | irq       0%  |               | idle     63%  | wait      0%  |               |               | steal     0%  | guest     0%  | curf 2.59GHz  | curscal   ?%  |
CPL | avg1    0.35  |               | avg5    0.10  | avg15   0.13  |               |               | csw     7047  |               | intr    3252  |               |               | numcpu     1  |
MEM | tot   991.5M  | free    9.2M  | cache   9.0M  |               | dirty   0.0M  | buff    0.1M  | slab   15.4M  |               |               |               |               |               |
SWP | tot     0.0M  | free    0.0M  |               |               |               |               |               |               |               |               | vmcom   1.4G  | vmlim 495.8M  |
PAG | scan   35266  |               |               | stall      0  |               |               |               |               | swin       0  |               |               | swout      0  |
DSK |         xvda  | busy      2%  | read     830  |               | write     74  | KiB/r     14  | KiB/w     13  | MBr/s   1.17  |               | MBw/s   0.10  | avq     1.83  | avio 0.26 ms  |
NET | transport     | tcpi     641  | tcpo     358  | udpi       5  | udpo       5  | tcpao      2  | tcppo      2  | tcprs      0  | tcpie      0  | tcpor      1  | udpnp      0  | udpip      0  |
NET | network       | ipi      646  | ipo      342  |               | ipfrw      0  | deliv    646  |               |               |               |               | icmpi      0  | icmpo      0  |
NET | eth0    ----  | pcki     630  | pcko     326  | si  340 Kbps  | so   95 Kbps  | coll       0  |               | mlti       0  | erri       0  | erro       0  | drpi       0  | drpo       0  |
NET | lo      ----  | pcki      16  | pcko      16  | si    1 Kbps  | so    1 Kbps  | coll       0  |               | mlti       0  | erri       0  | erro       0  | drpi       0  | drpo       0  |

  PID       RUID           EUID            THR        SYSCPU        USRCPU        VGROW        RGROW        RDDSK        WRDSK       ST       EXC       S       CPUNR        CPU       CMD        1/1
 6156       www-data       www-data          1         0.22s         0.78s       103.0M       102.5M        3644K          12K       --         -       R           0        10%       apache2
 6152       www-data       www-data          1         0.04s         0.56s       -1280K       -2256K          36K          12K       --         -       S           0         6%       apache2
 6452       www-data       www-data          1         0.03s         0.49s        -396K       -1440K           0K           0K       --         -       S           0         5%       apache2
 7466       www-data       www-data          1         0.10s         0.26s       54108K       55692K        2644K           0K       --         -       R           0         4%       apache2
```

...

Comment: Why do you have _so many_ apache2 processes? Try [some basic tuning](http://serverfault.com/a/447582/126632).

Comment: I don't know this came out of the box. I am using Chef to configure the server. May be I should mention that in my question. Thanks for the lead. I will update my question accordingly

Comment: Yep, those are absurdly high numbers for a small VPS.

Comment: Actually I have now tuned down the number of servers, but that doesn't seem enough, I have update my question accordingly

Comment: You seem to have plenty of free memory now?

Comment: oh this is after accessing the website once... if I access my website through 5 or 6 URL simultaneously, then I run into the same memory issue

Comment: You still have too many Apache processes, considering their high memory usage. Are you running some memory hungry PHP app?

Comment: it's a self hosted wordpress

Comment: With a few dozen plugins, no doubt. So the answer is yes :) Keep on tuning.

Comment: Prefork mpm is known to cause memory issues. What is your apache compiled on? Try with worker mpm.

Answer (score 0):

Following  Michael's recommendations and tuned down my `apache2.conf` a maximum on my `staging` instance. These are not `production` settings but they address my question.

```
# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          1
    MinSpareServers       1
    MaxSpareServers       2
    ServerLimit           5
    MaxClients            3
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          1
    ServerLimit           3
    MaxClients            3
    MinSpareThreads       10
    MaxSpareThreads       20
    ThreadsPerChild       64
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```